# Schedule a Java job to run once a week with different parameters each time

Tags: java, linux, cron

So I am currently designing an invoicing system that is meant to be run once a week. We separate our customers into 4 cycles that run once a week. What is the best way to schedule a Cron job to run once a week but to have a specific argument each time based on what day of the month it is. For example I want all customers that receive invoices on the 8th of the month to be sent out at 12:00AM on the 8th of each month. The next week I want to run the exact same program except I want to run it for the 15th. Should I have four separate jobs with 4 specific parameters that all run once a month or is there a sleeker way to keep everything in one program and one job that runs weekly but with different arguments? Am I overthinking it?

Answer (score 1):

While dealing with sensitive business problems like the one you have described, I would never rely on `cron` scheduling to manage state. I would rather leave the state management entirely to the program.

So, it is best to use a database or a file that stores the state so that scheduling has no influence on what your program does.  With that approach, you can have a single `cron` job that is run once a week.

The state information to be stored (based on what you have stated):

- customer
- cycle number
- last run date

The program must be capable of:

- Not repeating (if it is run again within the same week, it should never **repeat** a cycle)
- Fill the gap (if we run it after a gap of a week or more, it should be able to run all the **missed** cycles)

Comment: That makes sense, I do have customer ID, Cycle number i.e. (01,08,15,22) but i dont have last run date. I was thinking of having a few program arguments one of them being an entire cycle i.e. all of the customers to be sent a 1 cycle, and then also to accept individual customer ID's in the case of one not being sent, or having to resend or any other anomalies. I agree the program should have full control over which ones are sent and not leaving that up to cron but if for instance it runs on the 7th at midnight should I have some logic like current date +1 day to get all of the 08 cycles?

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking it ;)
You can have cron entry for all 4 cycles like this:

```
0 0 8,15,22,29 * * command
```

and add case switch or if statements checking the day of month with date +"%d", but this would over complicate the task. Not to mention readability.

Other approach would be creating a wrapper script that would hold all the 'case' logic mentioned above and set the wrapper as a cron command. 
e.g.

```
day_of_month=$(date +'%d')
case "${day_of_month}" in
'8') params='your params here' ;;
...
esac
/your/program "${params}"
```

You can always keep it simple and use 4 separate crontab entries.

Comment: Hmm yeah I can't decide between 4 seperate cronjobs or one that runs weekly. This seems like a super simple problem but It has to be 100% accurate in the sense that it doesnt miss any customers on a given cycle and also doesnt send one that isn't on the current cycle

Comment: Cron will run whatever you tell it to run. However @codeforester has a good point (I cannot comment everywhere yet ;)) - it's better approach to keep business logic separate. E.g. you run a program from cron weekly, program checks the schedule and runs only what it is supposed to run. I'm a database guy, so I'd keep it in a database, store all the items in a schedule table, program would read all entries scheduled for today, run all separately (so error in one entry doesn't break everything), and post status (last run date, sucess/failure message) back to the DB.